# resetting the terminal

Tags: terminal

In the Terminal `Shell` menu, there are two options for reset: `Hard Reset` and `Reset`. The former clears your screen; the latter just fixes it after nasty escape sequences.

It appears that `Hard Reset` is equivalent to the bash builtin `reset`. What is `Reset` (the softer version) equivalent to? `stty sane`?

(I would like to reset my terminal after an SSH connection disconnects without clearing the screen; the menu option is working for me but I would like it to be automatic.)

Comment: It is not exactly equivalent to stty sane, which can be shown with a small experiment: Run sh, so that your shell does not reset the tty to sane values. Run stty -echo, to turn off echo. Run stty sane, and echo comes back. Then do stty -echo again, and soft-reset the terminal. Still no echo. Also, stty sane and a terminal reset *should* affect different things. stty controls the operating system's interface to the terminal, while a terminal reset affects the terminal itself (which would have been a different piece of hardware, back in the day of actual terminals).

Answer (score 1):

Probably `stty sane` though there are also various reset strings that vary by terminal and the `TERM` type (`rs1` and ilk, see [`terminfo(5)`](http://man.openbsd.org/terminfo.5)) that may or may not be in use, and it's hard to debug something that is usually intercepted by the terminal itself to figure out what the exact bytes are. For example `Terminal.app` with `TERM=xterm` shows different reset escape sequences than `TERM=xterm-256color` does:

```
% infocmp | grep rs'[123]'
    rmul=\E[24m, rs1=\Ec, rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7,
% echo $TERM
xterm
% TERM=xterm-256color infocmp | grep rs'[123]'
    rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m, rs1=\Ec\E]104\007,
    rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7,
```

For automatic cleanup a shell function that wraps `ssh` with may suffice; the following one takes efforts to try to preserve the shell exit code (which is not the same as the 16-bit exit status word actually returned by a program) and resets various things. Whether this suffices for you depends on exactly what the remote end is doing and exactly how you want to clean that up.

```
function ssh() {
   local ret
   command ssh "$@"
   ret=$?
   stty sane
   # (optional) reset string, see terminfo(5)
   tput rs1
   # (optional) clear junk linux likes to spam terminal title bar with
   printf "\033]2;\007"
   return $ret
}
```

[More methods to reset the terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79684/fix-terminal-after-displaying-a-binary-file).